# setOnScrollListener infinite loop and loaded without scrolling in GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a problem with implementing setOnScrollListener in gridview when new data is continously loaded in a loop without user scrolling. I want to wait for user to scroll to the end and only then to load new data. How to accomplish that? This is the code that gives me infinite loop without scrolling:

```
  gv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

            load_more_data();

            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
            //      customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
            return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html), has the `onScroll` which provides you info abut the `firstVisibleItem`, the index of the first visible cell, `visibleItemCount`, the number of visible cells and `totalItemCount` the number of items in the list adaptor. If you implement it in the following method

```
 @Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
     if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount - 10) {
       load_more_data();
     }
 }
```

you app will start loading the next items when the threshoid `totalItemCount - 10`, is reached.

Comment: yes but it's happen without scrolling? it goes automaticaly?

Comment: what do you mean by *automatically*  ?

Comment: automaticaly - without user scrolling, it's just loads as app starts, until no more data, and replaces items in gridview, instead of waiting for scroll and add items to gridview

Comment: how is this thing related to your original question ?

Comment: automatically it means without user scrolling.. and as loading it just replaces my items, i would like to add them . this is the code gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, List1, List2,List3));

Comment: so can you help me on either?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount - 5)
            {
                load_more_data();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: hey i tried this code, but the problem is same. It is autoloading data instead of waiting for scroll, and replaces items instead of adding